# Count the occurence of values in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to count numbers of different values in mysql table columns. Range of possible values is integer and from 0-10. The following code is working, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this?

```
# Example data from Mysql
result = [{ :column1 => "2", :column2 => "3", :column3 => "1"},{ :column1 => "2", :column2 => "3", :column3 => "1"},{ :column1 => "1", :column2 => "2", :column3 => "3"}]

# Init hash
final_result = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = {  } }

# Loop result columns
result.each do |single_column|

    # Loop single items inside columns
    single_column.each do |single_result|

            # Create column if does not exist
            if final_result[single_result[0]][single_result[1]].nil? then
                final_result[single_result[0]][single_result[1]] = 1
            else
                final_result[single_result[0]][single_result[1]] += 1
            end
    end
end

puts final_result
# => {:column1=>{"2"=>2, "1"=>1}, :column2=>{"3"=>2, "2"=>1}, :column3=>{"1"=>2, "3"=>1}}
```

Comment: I don't think the change in title is right and voted against it. There is a better way of doing what is being asked for by using MySQL to do most of the work. So the original title is good IMO.

Answer (score 1):

There's some room for cleaning up here. The most obvious part is that long, clunky `if` statement. The test vs `nil?` is pointless, remember in Ruby the *only* things that are logically false are `false` and `nil`, so since `false` is never going to show up here, the test vs. `nil` specifically can be removed.

More than that, though, you're on the right track with the custom `Hash.new` call, but you don't go far enough. Why not initialize the second tier with zero?

That results in code that looks like:

```
result = [
  { :column1 => "2", :column2 => "3", :column3 => "1"},
  { :column1 => "2", :column2 => "3", :column3 => "1"},
  { :column1 => "1", :column2 => "2", :column3 => "3"}
]

# Init hash
final_result = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(0) }

# Loop result columns
result.each do |single_column|
  single_column.each do |r|
    final_result[r[0]][r[1]] += 1
  end
end

puts final_result.inspect
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the active record `count` method ([doc link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count)). You can use that in combination with `group` to do what you are trying to achieve.

```
[:column1, :column2, :column3].inject({}) do |hash, column|
  hash[column] = Model.group(column).count
  hash
end
```